# Многопоточное использование MySqlConnection

Tags: c#, многопоточность, mysqlconnector

В приложении необходимо использовать постоянно подключение к MySQL Серверу. Подключения производятся из разных потоков с разной интенсивностью.

Изучив немного вопрос использования Connector/NET написал следующий код:

```
public sealed class DatabaseManager
{
    private static Logger _log = new Logger("DatabaseManager");

    private static volatile DatabaseManager INSTANCE;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    private static MySqlConnection _connection;

    private static string host = "192.168.1.100";
    private static string database = "test";
    private static string user = "root";
    private static string password = "2223322";
    private static string _connectionString = "Data Source=" + host + ";Database=" + database + ";User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + password + ";Character Set=utf8";

    private DatabaseManager()
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    public void init()
    {
        _connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString);

        try
        {
            _connection.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand command = _connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS connection_test_table (`a` char(1) DEFAULT NULL)";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            _connection.Close();

            _log.info("Database connection activated successful.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _log.error("Attempting to connect to: " + database + "@" + host + "...", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    public void shutdown()
    {
        try
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _log.error("Error while closing Database connection.", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
        }

        try
        {
            _connection = null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _log.error("Errur while destroing connection object.", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    public MySqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        while (_connection == null)
        {
            if (_connection == null)
            {
                _connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString);
                _connection.Open();
            }
        }

        if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            _connection.Open();

        return _connection;
    }

    public static DatabaseManager getInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (INSTANCE == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (INSTANCE == null)
                        INSTANCE = new DatabaseManager();
                }
            }

            return INSTANCE;
        }
    }
}
```

Данный Singleton использую следующим образом (тестовый пример воткнул в таймер формы):

```
using (MySqlCommand command = DatabaseManager.getInstance.getConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE connection_test_table";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

При закрытии приложения использую вызов метода:

```
DatabaseManager.getInstance.shutdown();
```

Лог времени выполнения запросов (с учётом что MySQL сервер находится на другом ПК в локальной сети):

```html
23.02.2018, 19:44:32 [INFO]: Database connection activated successful.
23.02.2018, 19:44:32 [INFO]: Timestamp: Elapsed Time -> 0.410 sec.
23.02.2018, 19:44:33 [INFO]: Timestamp: Elapsed Time -> 0.028 sec.
23.02.2018, 19:44:34 [INFO]: Timestamp: Elapsed Time -> 0.018 sec.
23.02.2018, 19:44:35 [INFO]: Timestamp: Elapsed Time -> 0.011 sec.
23.02.2018, 19:44:36 [INFO]: Timestamp: Elapsed Time -> 0.024 sec.
23.02.2018, 19:44:37 [INFO]: Timestamp: Elapsed Time -> 0.019 sec.
23.02.2018, 19:44:38 [INFO]: Timestamp: Elapsed Time -> 0.010 sec.
23.02.2018, 19:44:39 [INFO]: Timestamp: Elapsed Time -> 0.063 sec.
23.02.2018, 19:44:40 [INFO]: Timestamp: Elapsed Time -> 0.040 sec.
```

Само создание подключения занимает около полсекунды. Время всех остальных запросов эквивалентно времени запросов из Navicat.

Так вот теперь сами вопросы:

1. Насколько корректно создана модель подключения к БД для многопоточного приложения?
2. Будет ли использоваться пул соединений или оно получается единственное в пуле?

P.S. Извиняюсь за профанство, но в Java, к примеру, используется не только Connector/J коннектор, но и пул менеджер, коих целый зоопарк. Самые распространённые: c3p0, HikariCP, BoneCP. И после создания подключения оно вызывается из пул менеджера.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но насколько я помню, пул соединений работает сам где то под капотом ADO.NET, потому руками как то им управлять не требуется

Comment: Реализация совершенна не корректна и абсолютна бессмысленна, ваш код не thread safe, синглтоны с состоянием зло, шарить mysqlconnection между потоками грех, об этом явно написано в доках https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html. Если уж так надо использовать именно ОДНО соединение (откуда такое ограничение?) то настройте пул на одно соединение, но при долгих запросов остальные потоки начнут отваливаться по таймауту.

Comment: ConnectionString в коде, тоже грех, чем App.config не устраивает? Лучше напишити фабрику для коннекшенов, которая будет вытаскивать ConnectionString из конфига, и возвращать MySqlConnection. И да, пул по умолчанию включен, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html

Comment: @PrimusSingularis, `ConnectionString` вместе с переменными впихнул в код примера чтобы не раздувать пост с разными зависимостями. Все настройки считываются из файла конфигурации и не являются хардкодными. И ещё. Меня больше всего интересовало как поддерживается пул. Именно из-за этого непонимания (не представления) самого процесса возникают фундаментальные ошибки в проектировании. Именно из-за этого мной была отклонена модель использования `MySqlConnect` при каждом новом обращении к БД.